# Blade conditional extends

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade, templating

I know this seems like an answered question, but it is not (I hope).

What I looking for is a way to extends or NOT a view: if the request is an ajax call the view does not extends nothing. Something like:

```
@if(!Request::ajax())

    @extends('navbar')

       @section('home')
          <div>"my content"</div>
       @stop

@else

    <div>"my content"</div>

@endif
```

This is NOT what I looking for:

```
@extends((( Request::ajax()) ? 'layouts.ajax' : 'layouts.default' ))
```

**I mean if the request is an ajax call, I want the view do not extend nothing.**

Hope to be clear.

Thx!

Comment: `@extends` must be the first line of code in the view and will accept only a ternary condition, exactly what you are not looking for.

Comment: is this a way to say: "you can not do that..."?

Comment: You can do this when you build the view instead of using @extends. Nest the view or don't based on your condition.

Comment: This can give you some ideas: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15226523/2094178

Comment: Solved... some times an @include could save your night! Sorry for waste of time...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved using the `@include` statement